# Add the count to new column pandas python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to remove duplicate lines and write the count of the occurrences using `pandas`. The following statement is what I tried:

```
createModel['count'] = createModel.groupby(createModel.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()
createModel.to_csv(r"test1.csv",index=False,header =True,sep="\t",encoding="utf-16")
createModel.head(10)
```

But I am getting error: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

I know that it is because I have added `count`. If I remove it and then try to save the file, I am only able to safe the `count`.

Please let me know how I can save the complete dataframe without duplicates and with a column added as `count` meaning the count of the number of times the line appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column, but necessary add one column value after `groupby` in `[]`:

```
cols = createModel.columns.tolist()
#another solution, thanks @jpp
#cols = list(createModel)
createModel['count'] = createModel.groupby(cols)[cols[0]].transform('size')
```

If need remove duplicated values need aggregate values and add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
createModel = createModel.groupby(cols).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: Or `cols = list(createModel)`.

Comment: Let me check it out.

Comment: I think if read in code `createModel.columns.tolist()` it is more clear it return columns names like `list(createModel)` :)

Comment: But this is not avoiding the duplicalies right? while I am trying to write it is file I see the previous file and the new files has same line counts. That means no duplicates were avoided.

Comment: But sir I do not want to index the column. As I know that the reset index column will make the `count` column my index.

Comment: @JafferWilson - It is perfectly OK, because `index=False` parameter in `to_csv` - index is not written to file.

Comment: ok I got your point sir.. Even I figured it out. I can using the method `drop_duplicates()` Your option is well.